# Acunetix can connect localhost

Tags: windows, localhost

I am runnig to error

> This site can’t be reached
>
> localhost unexpectedly closed the connection. ERR_CONNECTION_CLOSED

I cant access acunetix web interface localhost:8183 after crash.
Reinstaling acunetix, changing port, restarting windows, restarting services do not solve the problem.

How to solve problem?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That error indicates that the Acunetix service is either not started, or not listening on port 8183.

1. From Services, ensure that the Acunetix service is started
2. By default, you can access the Acunetix web interface from https://localhost:3443. You need to ensure that you use https, and if you did not change the port during installation, use the default port - 3443

[EDIT] arranged port 3443, which was incorrectly noted